# Need help creating slated or angled divs CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need help creating responsive divs with background images that have a slant or angle in them with no border to achvive a look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4zjs60k/

```
<div class="rr-left">

</div>
<div class="rr-right">

</div>
```

I have tried using background images with this solution, the only problem is the angled borders are color and if I add a background image to that it looks all messed up.

I've seen this one: http://codepen.io/jefflupinski/pen/azvsA but the only problem with the skew is that I need to have the left and right sides to be straight

So i was wondering if anyone has found a solution to make both divs touch and have responsive backgrounds or combine both in a way to incorporate images

thanks hopefully this makes sense

Comment: you won't be able to do this with a background image unless its tileable, because the angled section(s) is/are  pseudo `:before`/`:after` element(s).

Comment: is there a way to do it with out pseudo elements

Comment: split the background image, and use one piece in the element, one in the pseudo element. play with the background positioning until it lines up right.

Comment: might be able to use `-webkit-clip-path`.  See [this example](http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/ad12e1280e4b1c481faa3b82bd9a3263)

Answer (score 1):

Try the method below and adjust as needed.

```css
#holder {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: calibri;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
#holder .content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #2c3e50;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
#holder .content:hover {
  background-color: #425160;
}
.content:hover .line {
  background: #425160!important;
}
#holder .line {
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border-left: solid 1px white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 89%;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  background: inherit;
  height: 250px;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
p,
h3 {
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 70%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">

  <div class="content">

    <h3>This is a header</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>

  </div>

<div class="content">

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h3>This is a header</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>

  </div>


</div>
<!-- End Holder -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, using skew, but in a container that has overflow hidden

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    overflow: hidden;}

.right {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innerleft {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/800/400);
    transform: skew(20deg);
    left: 10%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.leftcontent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;

}

.right:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/600/500);
    transform: skew(20deg);
    right: 10%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="left">
    <div class="innerleft">
    <div class="leftcontent">LEFT</div>
    </div>
</div>    
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great this works perfectly, but when i try to put any content in it, it just pushes the background down any fix for that, thank you

Comment: Add an inner div with text on it.